# How can I run the same test cases for all the data in a list using testng?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, testng, testng-dataprovider

I am using data provider and test ng to run the same test multiple times using different values from a list. However, I have several tests and I want them all to run one by one so Test 1 -> Test 2 -> Test 3, for each item in the list. Right now Test 1 is running 4 times for all 4 elements in the list, and then Test 2 ->Test 3.

```
    @DataProvider
    public Object[][] data() throws CsvValidationException, IOException, URISyntaxException {
        ...get list..
        Object[][] element = new Object[list.size()][1];
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            element[i][0] = list.get(i);
        }
        return element;

    }

    @Test(dataProvider = "data",priority = 1)
    public void test(Element element) {
        System.out.println("test1");
    }
    
    @Test(priority=2)
    public void test2() {
        System.out.println("test2");

    }
```

So I want the output to be 'test1' 'test2'... 'test1' 'test2'...'test1''test2' not 'test1'..'test1'..'test1'..'test2'.

Answer (score 0):

The output order depends on the priority. Did you check the same priority in both tests?